# Do compiled C++ binaries store the original source code?

Tags: c++

When I run some C++ code, and I receive an error, it manages to print out the exact line in a particular source file on which that error occurred. This is obviously great for debugging, but I believe that the program I am running was built in release mode. So my questions is, do all programs built in release mode store the original source c++ code, with references to it in the compiled binary? This seems like an inefficient way to create a binary if it is only to be distributed to consumers, rather than to developers.

Comment: The simple answer is: No. However, when you build debug versions the compiler usually stores some information about the source, including line-number information and where the actual source files can be found. *How* the compiler stores that differs between compilers and platforms.

Comment: This is highly tool dependent. Describe your tool chain.

Comment: If you are talking about asserts, or similar methods, they don't store all your source-code, they only store the expression they're asserting (not that you should necessarily enable assertions in release).

Comment: @PeterT It really depends on the implementation: a lot do, but it isn't required.  (And in most cases, you _should_ leave assertions active in your released code.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never saw a "mainstream" C++ compiler store the original source. When you see some references to the source, typically it boils down to one of those tricks:

- references to source file/line: these are created via macros. Most logging libraries provide some macro that includes in its bowels the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` macros, which, *at compile time*, expands to the current file and line; macros like `__FUNCTION__` are a common extension;
- expressions in failed asserts: the `assert` macro (and similar beasts) often not only uses `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`, but stringifies (again, at compile time) the given expression, to show it when the `assert` fails;
- names of classes in the executable: if you enable RTTI, the compiler has to store somewhere the names of the types, to allow the use of the `typeid` operator;
- stuff you see in the debugger/in stack traces: this comes from the debugging information, which allows a reverse mapping from the instruction pointer to the location in the sources and the function name; this of course requires having the debug information (which may or may not be generated in release builds, or may be put in a separate file) and the actual sources (if you want to look up what the code actually is).

  Since this is both quite big (in a project I work on it is 12x the size of the stripped executable) and can help in reverse engineering, it is rarely shipped to the customer (but is kept in-house, to be able to analyze the "raw" stack traces generated by the released application).

Answer (score 2):

No.  Neither in debug nor in release mode are the actual sources stored.
The tool chain may store enough information for debugger to map
addresses in the machine code to lines in the sources, but the sources
must be available if the debugger is to display anything.  This has
nothing to do with "Debug" or "Release" mode; at least in our
configuration, we store it in both.  (Of course, because the compiler
may rearrange bits of code when it optimizes, the information isn't
always exploitable in optimized builds.)

As for the output of `assert`: C++ has two built in macros, `__FILE__`
and `__LINE__`, which the compiler will replace with the appropriate
values when it is compiling the code.  These are used in the `assert`
macro (typically, at least), and usually in various user defined logging
macros as well.  The macro preprocessor also has an operator to
"stringize" its arguments, which can be used to get the asserted
expression into the assert output.

Answer (score 0):

Compilers don't store the original source code. As mentioned, with a debug build, they store line numbers which are used to reference source code. There were some old tool sets (assemblers, compilers) that would leave fragments of source code in what should have been uninitialized memory in a program, just grabbing whatever happened to be in memory during assembly or compile time when creating the uninitialized memory area of a program. This mostly occurred with .COM program files since there's no provision for load time allocation of uninitialized memory as there is with a .EXE program.